# Backup files real quick

Tags: windows, backup

I am going to re-install WinXP but I have about 4gb of EverQuest files I want to keep which would otherwise be destroyed.  I don't have an external drive or an FTP server.  What is the best way to back this all up during the 45 minutes it takes to wipe her clean?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

SugarSync (a ripoff of Dropbox) gives 5GB of free storage
https://www.sugarsync.com/

Comment: You may want to compress the files first if you are going to upload them.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest and fastest way is probably borrow or buy a usb flash drive. Alternatively if you have fast internet, you can use [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) (although you would have to pay to upload more than 2GB).